# How do you make a Lego statue out of a character Model?

Tags: materials, modifiers, mathematics, procedural

I want to make a Lego esc statue out of a character Model.

The character Model has a texture.

My plan is to use the Remesh (Blocks) Modifier to make the Lego pieces. This works without a Problem.

[image][image]

I then plan to bake the Textures from the normal Model onto the Lego Model.

This should also work.

BUT. I then want the texture to be a solid colour for each block. Like actual Lego pieces.

[image]

Is there a procedural/mathematical way of modifying the texture to accomplish this ?

Any other ideas on how to change my process to get the result i want without manually texture painting everything?

Comment: May be worth looking into the Bricker addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/bricker